# jQuery UI dialog with boolean return - true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dialog

I´m trying to do an replacement for the **javascript** confirm(). I have found the jquery dialog() function that can be fully customized. The problem is that i cant make it return *true* or *false*.

Here is my code:

```
$('#delBox').dialog(
        { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, closeOnEscape: true, width: 300, height: 'auto', title: 'Deletar registro',
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    return true;
                }, "Cancelar": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            },
            open: function () {
                var buttonsSet = $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find("button:contains('Ok')");
                buttonsSet.attr("class", "ui-button ui-state-default");
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close span').empty();
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find("button:contains('Ok')").button({
                    text: false,
                    icons: {
                        primary: 'ui-icon-ok'
                    }
                });

                $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find("button:contains('Cancelar')").button({
                    text: false, 
                    icons: {
                        primary: 'ui-icon-cancel'
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This only return an object before any option selected:

```
function deletar() {
     alert($('#delBox').dialog('open'));
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

jQueryUI dialog boxes can't return a `true` or `false` as they're shown on top of other content but *without* blocking execution.

The best you can do is:

1. make the box `modal` so that it hides the other content
2. supply callbacks to be used depending on which option is chosen.

For extra bonus points, you could create a `$.Deferred()` promise object and return that when you show the dialog.  You can then `resolve` or `reject` that promise in the button event handlers.

This would give you clean separation between showing the dialog box, and performing the actions subsequently triggered by it:

```
function showDialog() {
   var def = $.Deferred();

   // create and/or show the dialog box here
   // but in "OK" do 'def.resolve()'
   // and in "cancel" do 'def.reject()'

   return def.promise();
}

showDialog().done(function() {
    // they pressed OK
}).fail(function() {
    // the pressed Cancel
});

// NB: execution will continue here immediately - you shouldn't do
//     anything else now - any subsequent operations need to be
//     started in the above callbacks.
```

Comment: Do you think the function should return the full-fledged Deferred object or a restricted Promise interface via `return def.promise()`?

Comment: @AtesGoral yes, `def.promise()` would be preferable - good point.

Comment: In `showDialog` do I have to bind the events to `OK` & `Cancel` using `$.one` i.e. the event will be added for one time execution each time `showDialog` is called? Is there a way to use `$.on` i.e. bind them once and use `showDialog` repeatedly?

Comment: @buffer you don't have to bind any events explicitly at all - just supply callbacks in the initial dialog options.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that if one doesn't use jQuery UI (i.e. have a custom modal dialog), can the event be added only once at init instead of doing it repeatedly inside `showDialog`?

Comment: @buffer no idea - depends on the implementation of the custom dialog.

Comment: didn't hit fail callback :(

Answer (score 7):

The first answer is fine - I thought I'd just add a bit of code showing how you can return the button that was clicked:

```
function ShowYesNoMessage(title, message) {
var def = $.Deferred();
$("#infoMessage").html(message);

$("#dialog_infoMessage").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: title,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            $("#infoMessage").html("");
            $(this).dialog("close");
            def.resolve("Yes");
        },
        No: function () {
            $("#infoMessage").html("");
            $(this).dialog("close");
            def.resolve("No");
        }
    }
});
return def.promise();
}


$.when(ShowYesNoMessage("Are you sure", message)).then(
            function(status) {
                if (status == "Yes") {
                    //do the next step
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Personally for a binary choice I prefer the `.resolve` / `.reject` combination.  Oh, and there's no need for a `$.when` if the function being called inside `$.when` returns a promise.