# Returning a Value from a jQuery Dialog Button Instead of Running a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an admin UI and I can't wrap my head around how to get a specific kind of modal behaviour. I'm using jQuery.

I already have a system for modal dialogs in place, where an `openModal(settings)` function opens a modal. Based on the settings, it will show/hide or sometimes inject various dialogs.

I also have a generic confirmation dialog and this is the one I'm not sure how to make work. The layout is simple:

```
<div id="confirmation-dialog">
    <h2>Are you sure?</h2>
    <button class="yes">Yes</button>
    <button class="no">No</button>
</div>
```

I could just hard-code each button to do what I need it to do but I would like this to be more generic. Ideally, I would like it to function like this: (I know this doesn't work)

```
function deleteImportantThing() {
    if (confirmThis() == true) {
        // Delete the thing
    } else {
        // Do nothing, close dialog
    }
}

function confirmThis() {
    openModal({kind: "confirm"});
    // Check which button is clicked, then return true or false
}
```

I guess I just don't know enough JavaScript to get this to work, or to even figure out where to look. Any advice?

I know there are modal dialog plug-ins out there but I'd have to change how the rest of my modals work to integrate them, and I'd like to do this myself if at all possible.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10703097/122005) may be useful.

Comment: @chridam Yes, that's very close to what I’m trying to do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your class names with dots can get a little fiddly, but you can wire up jquery behaviors to those buttons. Perhaps something along the lines of the following will get you there (or at least close):

```
// the two backticks are to escape the special 'dot' character within the class name
$(document).on('click', '.button\\.yes', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return true;// not entirely sure this will work as a 'confirm', so you might instead need to call some other function that accomplishes the desired task
});

$(document).on('click', '.button\\.no', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi there, there are no dots in the classname – I just typed it in wrong... The classes are just 'no' and 'yes'. I’ll try this, but wouldn’t 'return true' conflict with e.preventDefault()?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a conflict. But if you have some other default button behavior (or `a href` behavior if you later decide to change your markup), then that will keep the browser from doing what it wants and let you control what happens.