# Triggering event on clicking OK button in Jquery Modal dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to display a dialog box with just an OK button on response of an ajax call. When the user clicks OK, it should reload the page. But now page reload is immediately happening after the dialog box is popped up. It is not waiting for the user to click OK. FYI I am using Jquery Modal dialog box.

Simple browser alert() does the job for me, but I don't like the appearance of alert().

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
    url: "modules/mymod/save.php", 
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#requestForm').serialize(),
    statusCode: {404: function () {alert('page not found');}},
    success: function (data) {
        // alert(data);
        modal({type: 'alert', title: 'Alert', text: data});
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029730/open-a-popup-box-after-receiving-result-from-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Reference:](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.modal/blob/master/index.html)**

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "modules/mymod/save.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#requestForm').serialize(),
                statusCode: {404: function () {alert('page not found');}},
                success: function (data) {
                    // alert(data);
                    modal({
                        type: 'alert',
                        title: 'Alert',
                        text: data,
                        buttons: [{
                                text: 'OK', //Button Text
                                val: 'ok', //Button Value
                                eKey: true, //Enter Keypress
                                addClass: 'btn-light-blue btn-square', //Button Classes 
                                onClick: function() {
                                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                                }
                            }, ],
                        center: true, //Center Modal Box?
                        autoclose: false, //Auto Close Modal Box?
                        callback: null, //Callback Function after close Modal (ex: function(result){alert(result);})
                        onShow: function(r) {
                            console.log(r);
                        }, //After show Modal function
                        closeClick: true, //Close Modal on click near the box
                        closable: true, //If Modal is closable
                        theme: 'xenon', //Modal Custom Theme
                        animate: true, //Slide animation
                        background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.35)', //Background Color, it can be null
                        zIndex: 1050, //z-index
                        buttonText: {
                        ok: 'OK',
                        yes: 'Yes',
                        cancel: 'Cancel'
                    },
                    template: '<div class="modal-box"><div class="modal-inner"><div class="modal-title"><a class="modal-close-btn"></a></div><div class="modal-text"></div><div class="modal-buttons"></div></div></div>',
                    _classes: {
                    box: '.modal-box',
                    boxInner: ".modal-inner",
                    title: '.modal-title',
                    content: '.modal-text',
                    buttons: '.modal-buttons',
                    closebtn: '.modal-close-btn'
                      }
                    });
                   }
            });
```

Comment: @AdityaAmit try my solution. hope it will work in your scenario. Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution but the button click event doesn't trigger. Only the default behavior is coming.

Comment: @AdityaAmit you need to **[Check this link](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.modal/blob/master/index.html)** .

Comment: Thanks @Zaheer I added callback function to it. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `dialog` modal `buttons` attributes, each with a registered event, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "modules/mymod/save.php", 
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#requestForm').serialize(),
    statusCode: {404: function () {alert('page not found');}},
    success: function (data) {

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height: 200,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              Proceed: function() {
                 window.location.href = window.location.href;
              },
              Cancel: function() {
                 // Cancellation code here
              }
           }
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: OP is not using Jquery Dialog

Comment: @MayankPandeyz there's a jquery-ui-dialog tag.

Comment: @KobyDouek the problem is I cannot use confirm dialog box here. Because there is nothing to do on cancellation. I just want the page reload to wait till user clicks OK. Thanks.

Comment: @AdityaAmit so just leave the cancel function empty. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Because your reload runs irrespectively of what is clicked. If you want to assign a callback function to the modal window:

[jQuery UI dialog with boolean return - true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703071/jquery-ui-dialog-with-boolean-return-true-or-false)

Also, there is no need to make location.href equal itself (or use the window object). `location.reload()` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple browser alert() does the job for me** because alert() is an blocking call. If you omit the alert then your code is not bind with any event to check whether user clicked on a button or not, that's why the code block executes immediately and page reloads.

So bind the following code:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

inside some button click, to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

dont use window.location function in success.instead open the modal with ok button at success(how to do that, I think you know already) and assign some id to that button let say `id="loction_btn"`.
then use just this

```
$('document').on('click','#location_btn',function(){
   window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```